# Arrays.asList compilation problem

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I've used Arrays.asList dozens if not hundreds of times without problem.  All of a sudden previously compiling code is failing to compile after switching to NetBeans 6.9 from 6.8.  Here's a few lines in question:

```
Node n = new NickNode(4,5);
Node m = new NonLocatableNode();
Node subclass = new NickSubclassNode();

List<Node> nodes = Arrays.asList(n,m,subclass);
```

The subclasses of node are not important; they compile fine.  The line that gives me an error is the Arrays.asList line.  I get the error

[alt text http://grab.by/grabs/b553ffb898ca0874ef4741b8c87fc576.png](http://grab.by/grabs/b553ffb898ca0874ef4741b8c87fc576.png)

I have no idea where it's getting anything about a HelpCtx.Provider[]... Does anyone see anything wrong with this snippet?

Replacing the asList line with

```
List<Node> theNodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
theNodes.add(n);
theNodes.add(m);
theNodes.add(subclass);
```

works fine.  But I prefer the shorter syntax of Arrays.asList

Comment: A shorter workaround would probably be bypassing varargs: `theNodes = Arrays.asList(new Node[] {n, m, subclass});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
List<Node> nodes = Arrays.<Node>asList(n,m,subclass);
```

Comment: That worked.  I stumbled onto that syntax in the past (it is truly bizarre), but have *never* had to use it in the context of an Arrays.asList declaration.  Usually the type inferencing works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your error graphic is not showing up for me but it looks like a generics problem.  Perhaps a compiler warning was switched into a compiler error when you moved from netbeans 6.8 to 6.9?

Try declaring your List as ...

```
List<? extends Node> nodes = Arrays.asList(n, m, subclass);
```

The wildcard syntax specifies that the list contains Nodes and anything that inherits from Node.

Answer (score 2):

Yep you are right this is the bug in NetBeans 6.9 which is already reported.So hopefully it will get resolved soon. You can see that bug report [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183407)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but that bug report seems to be completely unrelated.  I'm not getting a null pointer exception at all.

Answer (score -1):

it should be:

```
List<? extends Node> nodes = Arrays.asList(n,m,subclass);
```

bear in mind that :

```
List<Sub Class> is not a sub class for List<Parent Class>
```

they are different classes.

Comment: n, m and subclass are all declared as a `Node`.  The runtime type is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Mark: n, m and subclass are all declared as a Node but  List<subclass> is not a List<Node>.  that's way you need to have ? extends Node as generic type.

Comment: You're right that, but in this case it doesn't matter, since asList will return a List<Node>, not a List<SubClassOfNode>.